# SQLite .Net 3.5 Provider returns all DataColumn(s) as System.Object

Tags: .net, sqlite

I have a method that takes an SQL string and returns a DataTable object from a SQLite data base.  This works just fine, but when I look at the DataColumns in the DataTable the DataType returned is always "System.Object".  How do I get it to return the correlating DataType that matches up with SQLite (ex.  VARCHAR2 = System.String, BOOL = System.Boolean, ....).  Below is the code I have for creating the DataTable.  Is there some addition step that I can get without having to hard code the appropriate type cast?

```
public DataTable                GetDataTable
(
string sql
)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        openConnection();
        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(m_cnn);
        mycommand.CommandText = sql;
        SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        closeConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new DatabaseException(DatabaseException.DatabaseExceptionTypes.GetDataTable,e);
    }
    return dt;
    enter code here
```

Comment: which version of .NET driver?

Comment: I use a recent one which correctly retrieves the datatype as well. How are you checking the datatype? Furthermore I suspect if SQLite has anything like a bool datatype